# Delete record with composite primary key in MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datacontext

I have a method in my controller that if a user clicks a button it will subscribe them to a ticket or remove them from the subscription if they are already subscribed. It does this by adding the TicketId and UserId to a ticket subscription table and if that record already exists it is supposed to delete it from the table.  I have the adding a subscription portion working but I cannot get the delete it from the table to work.  Here is the code that I have for the delete:

```
var ticketId = db.Tickets.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TicketNumber == ticketNumber).TicketId;
var userId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NTUserName.Equals(User.Identity.Name)).UserId;

bool subscriptionExists = db.TicketSubscriptions.Any(ts => ts.TicketId.Equals(ticketId) && ts.UserId == userId);
if (subscriptionExists)
{
     TicketSubscription ticketSubscription = db.TicketSubscriptions.Find(ticketId,userId);

     ticketSubscriptions.Delete(ticketSubscription);

}


internal DataContext context;
internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

public RepositoryBase(DataContext context)
{
     this.context = context;
     this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
}
public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
{
     if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
         dbSet.Attach(entity);

     dbSet.Remove(entity);
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error on the dbSet.Remove(entity) line:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An entity object cannot be referenced by
>   multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.

and there is no inner exception.

Comment: Off topic: you either user `FirstOrDefault` and check if the result is null before using it, or you go directly with `First`, using `FirstOrDefault` and then accessing the result directly makes no sense.

Comment: What is `context` and `dbSet`? If i understand correct it's 2 different EFConexts. If so - use only one context to operate with your entity.

Comment: You could also rewrite your code to perform a direct `TicketSubscriptions` lookup and then checking if a subscription is found or not. `db.TicketSubscriptions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Ticket.TicketNumber == ticketNumber && a.User.NTUserName == User.Identity.Name)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934376/an-entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetra)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker. while adding related objects to entity in Entity Framework 4.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191734/entity-object-cannot-be-referenced-by-multiple-instances-of-ientitychangetracker)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I ended up fixing the problem.

1) I added a primary key that was not a composite

2) I changed the repositorybase method for delete to be the following:

```
public virtual void Delete(object id)
{
     TEntity entity = dbSet.Find(id);

     if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
          dbSet.Attach(entity);

     dbSet.Remove(entity);
     context.SaveChanges();

}
```

3) then I passed in the new primary key to this method