# dbContext An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

So the problem I'm having is the following. When going into this if statement, then I want to delete all the entries with ClearDbInstallForGroupAndHeader() from table InstallationBOM. Then I want to add all the entries within NewInstallationBoms into my InstallationBOM table and while doing this calculating total cost, but when I want to add it with this line **db.InstallationBOMs.Add(newInstallationBom);**, I get the following error:
    **An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.**

```
 if (InstallationSelected)
 {
      bool newEntry = true;
      if (SelectedQuoteDetails != null)
      {
          QuoteDetail theQuoteDetail = SelectedQuoteDetails.FirstOrDefault(X => X.GroupNr == groupID && X.LineType == "I");
          if (theQuoteDetail != null)
          {
               this.ClearDbInstallForGroupAndHeader();
               int position = SelectedQuoteDetails.IndexOf(theQuoteDetail);
               newEntry = false;
               theQuoteDetail.Quantity = InstallQty;
               theQuoteDetail.UnitCost = InstallCost;
               theQuoteDetail.UnitPrice = InstallPrice;
               SelectedQuoteDetails[position] = theQuoteDetail;

               db.QuoteDetails.Attach(theQuoteDetail);
               db.Entry(theQuoteDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
               db.SaveChanges();

              decimal totalInstallationCost = 0;
              totalInstallationCost = AddInstallToDbCalcTotalCost(theQuoteDetail.Line.Value, groupID);

              newLines.UnitCost = totalInstallationCost;
              newLines.UnitPrice = newLines.UnitCost * (1 + (Settings.MarginPercentage / 100));

              InstallCost = newLines.UnitCost ?? 0;
              InstallPrice = newLines.UnitPrice ?? 0;                                        

              RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedQuoteDetails);

          }
      }
  }

  public void ClearDbInstallForGroupAndHeader()
    {
        try
        {
            using (QuoteConfiguratorEntities db = Utilities.GetContext())
            {
                List<InstallationBOM> dbList = db.InstallationBOMs.Where(x => x.QuoteHeaderId == this.SelectedQuoteHeader.ID && x.GroupNr == this.SelectedGroup.ID)
                                                        .ToList();
                foreach (InstallationBOM existingInstallationBom in dbList)
                {
                    db.InstallationBOMs.Remove(existingInstallationBom);
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Message = ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            this.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
    }

    public decimal AddInstallToDbCalcTotalCost(decimal pLine, long pGroupNr)
    {
        decimal totalInstallationCost = 0;
        try
        {
            using (QuoteConfiguratorEntities db = Utilities.GetContext())
            {
                foreach (InstallationBOM newInstallationBom in this.NewInstallationBoms)
                {
                    newInstallationBom.QuoteHeaderId = this.SelectedQuoteHeader.ID;
                    newInstallationBom.GroupNr = pGroupNr;
                    newInstallationBom.LineNumber = pLine;
                    totalInstallationCost += (newInstallationBom.Quantity.Value *
                                              newInstallationBom.Cost.Value);
                    db.InstallationBOMs.Add(newInstallationBom);                       
                    db.SaveChanges();   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Message = ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace;
            this.ShowErrorMessage();
        }
        return totalInstallationCost;
    }

public void OpenInstallationOptionsWindow(bool AsThread = false)
    {
        try
        {
            if (AsThread)
            {
                this.Busy = true;
                this._Thread = new Thread(() => QuoteConfiguratorViewModel.OpenInstallationOptionsWindow(this));
                this._Thread.IsBackground = true;
                this._Thread.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                using (QuoteConfiguratorEntities db = Utilities.GetContext())
                {
                    ObservableCollection<InstallationBOM> installBomListGroup = new ObservableCollection<InstallationBOM>(db.InstallationBOMs.Where(x => x.QuoteHeaderId == this.SelectedQuoteHeader.ID
                        && x.GroupNr == this.SelectedGroup.ID).ToList());
                    if (installBomListGroup != null)
                    {
                        if (!installBomListGroup.Any())
                        {
                            ClearInstallationBomEntry();
                            NewInstallationBoms = new ObservableCollection<InstallationBOM>();
                        }
                        else if (installBomListGroup.Any())
                        {
                            NewInstallationBoms = installBomListGroup;
                        }
                    }                        

                    Messenger.Default.Send<OpenInstallationWindow>(new OpenInstallationWindow());

                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Message = Utilities.GetError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wow, If you split your methods, it's easier to see the problem. 7 save changes in one method ? That's mean you have to have at least 7 methods. After this probably you will see the problem yourself.

Comment: but you are definitely correct regarding this. I will take your advise and post the revised code when I'm done

Comment: posted some revised code

Comment: Where and how is `NewInstallationBoms` initialized? Does it contain any tracked/proxy objects from the database?

Comment: I'll post the OpenInstallationOptionsWindow as well where  NewInstallationBoms is initialized

Comment: how can I see what is being tracked and the states of entities in runtime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `NewInstallationBoms` are attached in a context. But you try to add them in another context in `AddInstallToDbCalcTotalCost`.

Solution 1: You should use same context. Detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10194299/3432471)

Solution 2: You should first detach them in first context and attach them in second context. Detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16940690/3432471).

Solution 3 (Credits to [grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40)): If you use `AsNoTracking()` in first context. It will not be tracked/cached. Therefore you can safely use it in second context.

In your stiuation it's better to follow solution 1. If you use dependency injection container, you can make your dbcontext as per request.
Other than this,you can manage lifetime of dbcontext on upper level or you can make your class disposable and manage db context in your class.

Comment: Solution 3: query with `AsNoTracking()`